# What is the most efficient way to track when a selectize widget is locked?

Tags: selectize.js

I am building a widget that uses a selectize and another button. I want to make sure the button is disabled whenever the selectize is locked. What is the best way to do this?

As far as I can tell, there's nothing in the selectize API to hook into. Also, I cannot anticipate all the actions that cause the selectize to be locked, because some of them are internal to the selectize.

Comment: what does locked mean? disabled? has a value selected?

Comment: Locked is functionally disabled, but not visually so, used to temporarily stop input. It's part of the selectize api, documented here: https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#methods_other

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this not by disabling the button, but instead by checking if the selectize is locked in the button click event handler. This works well because the appearance of the widget and button shouldn't really change when the selectize is locked anyway.

```
function myClickHandler(ev) {
    if (mySelectize.isLocked) return;

    // do stuff
}
```

---

As far as I can tell, the best way to track the locked state as I originally intended would be to write a plugin that provides hooks for becoming locked and unlocked. (Let us know if you find one!)